# Статические константы класса и что с ними делать?

Tags: c++

У меня есть два класса, которые раскинуты по разным хэдэрам и сурсным файлам, при этом в каждом из них есть некоторое количество статических констант, вроде:

```
//a.hpp
class A {
public:
    static const Koord a;
}

//b.hpp
class B {
public:
    static const Koord a;
}
```

где Koord - это свой класс (не имеет статических констант). При этом `A.a` зависит от `B.a` и, поэтому для инициализации `B.a` нужно уже определенная `A.a`... Иначе, конечно проблема. Так вот: как и где лучше проинициализировать эти статические константы? Я вынес обе инициализации из обоих классов в один отдельный файл и все работает как надо, но выглядит не камильфо, когда в одном файле происходит такое:

```
const Koord B::a = 1;
const Koord A::a = B::a + 1;
```

Comment: Может быть стоит поменять дизайн, выглядит не очень, что какие-то константны зависят друг от друга и используются в разных сущностях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если глобальная переменная (пусть и `const`) зависит от другой глобальной, то они как минимум должны быть определены в одной единице трансляции. Иначе, может возникнуть ситуация, именуемая *static initialization order fiasco*. Т.к. языком не гарантируется порядка инициализации глобальных переменных между разными единицами трансляциями. Пока всё живёт в одном файле проблем быть не должно.

Comment: тобишь кроме как забивать в один файл - вариантов нет?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch можно попробовать сделать синглтон, который будет гарантировано возвращать инициализованный `B::a`. И использовать это значение при инициализации `A::a`.

Comment: хм, интересно...

Comment: А вариант сделать их статическими функциями не годится?

Comment: @bipll в этом случае постоянно будет создаваться значение Koord - не самый оптимальный вариант

Comment: ? Какое значение, где создаваться? `static Koord const &a() { static const Koord retVal; return retVal; }`?

Comment: @bipll а, да, так не будет. Только замените с `static Koord const` на 'static const Koords`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch: будет возвращаться константная ссылка дабы вы не меняли ее значение, там все правильно написано. А еще сам метод стоит пометить как константный.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Не обязательно. `const` можно переставлять в пределах типа, я так привык писать константные ссылки.